# What is the @r property of a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, p5.js

While trying out the [p5.js web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/), I came across the following:

[image: Web editor screenshot]

[Link to the sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/ARatherLongUsername/sketches/rJQTyi9_7)

If you take a look at the console, you'll notice that saying `Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(0));` apparently creates an array with 3 Objects, each with an `@r` of 1 (and nothing else).

You can also see that when I add different objects using a nested for-loop, any of the arrays don't seem to have the `@r` property.

---

I understand that what I'm doing here is referencing the same Array object thrice, which might be what the 'r' stands for, however, I can't see the `@r` property showing up anywhere else.

I've tried the same in the Chrome console and Node, but the same code doesn't bring up an `@r` property.

### Chrome Console

[image: Chrome console]

### Node

[image: Node]

---

StackOverflow's HTML snippet does something a bit more sensible, but still no `@r`:

### HTML Snippet

```js
let a = Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(0));
console.log(a);
```

---

My questions are the following:

- What actually is `@r`?
- Do any JavaScript Objects actually have an `@r` property?

  - If so

    - Why is it that the mentioned consoles don't show it?
    - Is there a way to access the `@r` value of an object?
  - If not

    - Why does it show up here?

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but I think it's going to come down to something internal to arrays in JavaScript that you shouldn't worry about too much. Also note that `let a = Array(3);` ends up containing an `@t` field.

Comment: @KevinWorkman  What's an `@t` field?

Comment: I guess its just the feature of that console to show 'same refference ' of those variables with @r.

Comment: I don't know. I'm guessing it's similar to the `@r` field. Try changing your line to mine and seeing what prints out.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar I thought that too, but what I was looking for is whether or not this is applicable throughout javascript. and why is it that it shows up here

Comment: @Rabbid76 In this case, a screenshot of the console output is pretty much required

Comment: This seems to be specific to the Processing language. The editor seems to transpile the code, and instead of plain values it passes around type-annotated objects.